# What is the correct way to retrieve length of an array added a field in nested struct in golang

Tags: go, struct, nested, variable-length

I have a nested struct and I need to find the length of an array which is one of the fields in the struct.

Here are the structs :

```
type TextEntry struct{
     name string
     Doc []DocEntry
}
```

```
type DocEntry struct {
     rank: int
     last: string
     forward: string
}
```

Here's the struct initializer

```
a := TextEntry{
        name: "a1",
        Doc: []DocEntry{
            {
                rank:    1,
                last:    "a2",
                forward: "always",
            },
            {
                rank:    2,
                last:    "b2",
                forward: "seldom",
            },
        },
    }
```

My question is to use the correct way to find the length of []DocEntry which will be the value of Doc in TypeEntry struct

Comment: `len(a.Doc)`? Are you asking how to find the length of the slice assigned to the `Doc` field?

Comment: Note that none of your code contains arrays. You're actually asking about slices. And the way to determine the length is with `len()`.

Comment: Yeah - need to find the length of the slice and the solution you provided worked. Seemed too confusing but looks like it had a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
len(a.Doc)
```

BTW you have syntax error in your "DocEntry" struct definition.
For full code please look at [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wYc9etXw94z).